# Can I route a call via SIP based on a phone number using native SIP android?

Tags: settings, calls, voip, sip

My Android 4.x phone supports SIP.

However, the options when to use the "Internet calling" are very limited: "For all calls", "Only for Internet calls", "Ask for each call".

I would like to use Internet (SIP) calls based on phones number (e.g. all international and long-distance calls should go via SIP, all phone number starting with +395656 xxx and local calls should go via my regular voice account).

I don't want to use any application like csipsimple, I want to use native support.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use 3rd party apps, this is currently (as of Android version 4.4) not possible.